# My footer link CSS styles aren't working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

The links on my footer are not working. The links are not hoverable or clickable.

---

I'm sorry, I should have added that the z-index on the footer is set to -999 so that it stays behind the main content. Is there a work around if that is the issue?

```
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About EIC</a></li>            
    </ul>
</footer>
```

```css
footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8em;
    background-color: e0e0e0;
    z-index: -999;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
footer li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 2em;
}
footer a:link {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
footer a:hover {
    color: #999;
}
```

[View it on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Vsvg2/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `z-index: -999` on the footer moves it behind the actual document. So the links are not clickable or hoverable.

Actually, this kind of problem is easily noticable when using the "Inspect Element" feature of firebug or firefox's developer tools. Inspecting the link will not select the link but rather your document - that tells you that the link is behind something (the element that was inspected instead of the link).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `z-index: -999` declaration. Your footer is behind the clickable page area.

Comment: Alright, that solves the link problem, but I have the z-index set that way so that the sticky footer stays behind the content of the page. Without it, it clips the content. Could you recommend a work around?

Answer (score 0):

What the above people said, plus your missing a # for you background color.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vsvg2/8/

Comment: Sorry about the confusion - the fiddle does have the problem corrected as the z-index was changed. but I realized others had answered already - just wanted to include the other minor fix.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}
```

from your css.

**Edit:**

you still have to remove z-index: -999;
Thank you animuson for correcting me.

Comment: This would only work so long as the page content did not expand it back to that height. It doesn't solve the underlying issue.